# Copying files into multiple folders depending on name

Tags: bash, file-copy

I have folders nested various levels deep, with names such as `x/y/z/Drawings` and `a/b/c/x/y/z/Plans`. There might be hundreds of upper-level folders that contain a `Drawings` or `Plans` sub-folder somewhere in their path.

I then have icons called `Drawings.jpg` and `Plans.jpg`. I'd like to copy the correct JPG into all the correct (i.e., correspondingly-named) sub-folders. That is, for every `../Drawings` folder, wherever it may be in the folder hierarchy, I'd like to see a `../Drawings/Drawings.jpg`, and a `../Plans/Plans.jpg` file.

I'm running on Ubuntu, but I cannot think of way of doing a copy of file named `Whatever.jpg` into every single sub-folder that is named `something/something/Whatever`. The problem is basically one of single-file source being copied into multiple destinations, based on folder name.

There are likely no more than 15 JPGs that have to be housed appropriately, but there are hundreds of possible destination sub-folders for each JPG.

Is there a series of simple `cp` commands I can use to achieve this? Or a bit of Bash script that will produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are happy to consider non-leaf directories as candidates for the copy command, you can base the solution from `find`.

```
iconDir=/path/to/icons_directory
rootDir=/path/to/top/of/drawings_projects_etc

find "$rootDir" -type d -exec sh -c '
    iconDir="$0"
    for thisDir in "$@"
    do
        iconName="${thisDir##*/}.jpg"
        [ -f "$iconDir/$iconName" ] && echo cp -p "$iconDir/$iconName" "$thisDir"
    done
' "$iconDir" {} +
```

What this does is to consider every directory under `$rootDir` in turn. It looks for an icon file in your `$iconDir` corresponding to the last part of the directory path (suffixed with `.jpg`), and if one is found it's copied to the target directory.

As written, you'll get only a statement of intended action. Remove the `echo` prefix from `cp` to make it actually copy the files.

I use `cp -p` rather than `cp` to retain permissions and - often more usefully - the timestamp of the original file. If your `$iconDir` and all of your `$rootDir` tree are all on the same filesystem you might prefer to use `ln` rather than `cp -p`.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
for icon (path/to/icons/*.jpg(N.))
  for dir (path/to/dirs/**/$icon:t:r(N/))
    cp $icon $dir/
```

To speed it up, there are a number of optimisations you could do:

- build a list of all dirs first and reuse it so not to have to crawl the `path/to/dirs` directory tree for each icon
- make `cp` builtin to remove the cost of forking a process and executing an external command for each copy
- do `N`ot `o`rder the globs as we don't really need them to be sorted here.
- disabling multibyte character support as doing byte-to-byte comparisons is enough here.

So

```
zmodload zsh/files
set +o multibyte
dirs=(path/to/dirs/**/*(N/oN))
for icon (path/to/icons/*.jpg(N.oN))
  for dir (${(M)dirs:#*/$icon:t:r})
    cp $icon $dir/
```

(of those, what is going to make the most difference is `zmodload zsh/files` which enables a builtin `cp`).

You may want to use `ln` or `ln -sr` (`-r` is a GNU extension and not supported by `zsh`'s builtin `ln` though) instead of `cp` to make links instead of copies to save space.